# Replace Special Characters function issue

Tags: utf-8, character-encoding, ascii, special-characters, utf8-decode

I am using a function I found on Stackoverflow to replace some special characters:

```
function toASCII( $str )
{
    return strtr(utf8_decode($str), 
        utf8_decode(
        'ŠŒŽšœžŸ¥µÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖØÙÚÛÜÝŐŰßàáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõöøùúûüýÿőű'),
        'SOZsozYYuAAAAAAACEEEEIIIIDNOOOOOOUUUUYOUsaaaaaaaceeeeiiiionoooooouuuuyyou');
}
```

However, when I try the functionality in HTML I do not get the desired result. HTML code:

```
<?php 
$test = 'ŠŒŽšœžŸ¥µÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖØÙÚÛÜÝŐŰßàáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõöøùúûüýÿőű';

$test1 = toASCII($test);
?>

!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en-US" lang="en-US">

   <head>

       <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
   </head>
   <body>
        <?php echo $test."<br>";
              echo $test1;
        ?>

     </body>
</html>
```

Result in Browser:

```
ŠŒŽšœžŸ¥µÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖØÙÚÛÜÝŐŰßàáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõöøùúûüýÿőű
uuuuuuuYuAAAAAAACEEEEIIIIDNOOOOOOUUUUYuusaaaaaaaceeeeiiiionoooooouuuuyyuu
```

Any ideas why some characters are shown as `u` instead of the desired one?

Note: I would prefer to avoid using `setlocale` since it would required additional changes in the code.

Answer (score 0):

When you use strtr() with three arguments, it operates with bytes and not with multibyte characters (see http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php#111270). Instead you have to give an array that contains an exact mapping.

This would be a solution for your case:

```
<?php 

function mbStringToArray( $str ) {
    return preg_split('//u', $str, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
}

function toASCII( $str ) {
    $map = array_combine(
        mbStringToArray('ŠŒŽšœžŸ¥µÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖØÙÚÛÜÝŐŰßàáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõöøùúûüýÿőű'),
        mbStringToArray('SOZsozYYuAAAAAAACEEEEIIIIDNOOOOOOUUUUYOUsaaaaaaaceeeeiiiionoooooouuuuyyou')
    );
    return strtr($str,$map);
}

$test = 'ŠŒŽšœžŸ¥µÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖØÙÚÛÜÝŐŰßàáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõöøùúûüýÿőű';
$test1 = toASCII($test);

?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en-US" lang="en-US">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    </head>
    <body>
    <?php
        echo $test."<br>";
        echo $test1;
    ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Output:

```
ŠŒŽšœžŸ¥µÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖØÙÚÛÜÝŐŰßàáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõöøùúûüýÿőű
SOZsozYYuAAAAAAACEEEEIIIIDNOOOOOOUUUUYOUsaaaaaaaceeeeiiiionoooooouuuuyyou
```